# Using insertBefore() to re-order table rows in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

I am trying to shift a table row up on click of a button using JavaScript. The below code is not shifting the row up. The alert statement after the `insertBefore` statement is also displayed.

```
function MoveUp(x) {

    var RowLocation = x.id;
    var table = dojo.byId('dynamicTable');
    var rows = table.rows;

    if ((RowLocation > 0) && (RowLocation < (rows.length - 1))) {
        alert('inside if..'+ RowLocation);
        rows.insertBefore(rows[RowLocation],rows[RowLocation-1]);           
        alert('after shift..');
    }
}
```

Can anyone help to find out the mistake?

Comment: can you show us the HTML code?

Answer (score 1):

You should call `insertBefore` on the parent of the newly inserted node (instead of `table.rows`):

```
var parentNode = rows[RowLocation].parentNode;
parentNode.insertBefore(rows[RowLocation], rows[RowLocation - 1]);
```

[See here:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.insertBefore)

```
var insertedElement = parentElement.insertBefore(newElement, referenceElement);
```

Use the following to move a row down:

```
var parentNode = rows[RowLocation].parentNode;
parentNode.insertBefore(rows[RowLocation], rows[RowLocation + 1].nextSibling)
```

Comment: Excellent. That one worked!! The inclusion of .parentNode made the difference. Thanks a lot..!

Comment: I am trying for row shift down with the similar logic. But its not worling. Could you please help?       rows[RowLocation].parentNode.insertAfter(rows[RowLocation],rows[RowLocation+1]);

Comment: `rows[RowLocation].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[RowLocation], rows[RowLocation + 1].nextSibling)`

Comment: rows[RowLocation].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[RowLocation],rows[RowLocation].nextSibling.nextSibling); This one worked. But the above(Rowlocation +1 ) didnt work. Any idea?

Comment: Right.In the fiddle it is working fine. Anyways, I will check it out. Thanks a lot for the help dude.